# Read geojson text

Tags: qgis, geojson

I know I can load a `geojson` **file** to QGIS and visualize it quickly. But I am still wondering whether there are some methods for me to paste the `geojson` **text** directly to QGIS just like the `QuickWKT` plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Python console.

The following works for me:

```
data='{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[72.79,19.12],[72.93,19.20]]}}]}'
my_layer = QgsVectorLayer(data, "DummyLine","ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(my_layer)
```